# How to modify jenkins dashboard?

Tags: user-interface, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed jenkins with the following steps.

- wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
- echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list
- sudo apt-get install jenkins

Now i would like to make small change like inserting one word to the front-end of the jenkins UI(dashboard)

Can anyone help me how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of change you are looking at?

Comment: say suppose i want to add text or something to existing HTML how can i do it.